# voltage cutoff for very low voltage (0.5v)

Tags: voltage, zener

I have a circuit that I want to not allow any voltage to go over 0.5v.
I read the voltage with ADC and the input can go from 0v to 0.5v and what I want is a circuit that will keep the voltage 0.5 even if it goes over 0.5v.
i have  looked for 0.5v zener diode but I didn't find any.
Thanks for your help

Comment: It depends on your source impedance. What is it?  I assume it is not 0 Ohms  then current limit into Sch Diode can be selected to match.

Comment: You cannot guarantee this accuracy with any diode alone. Why do you need this protection?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear - you've had several hours to provide more information.

Comment: There is a type of OpAmp circuit called *active clamp* (see fig.40 in this [app note](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01353A.pdf)).  It's hard to make a more informed suggestion without knowing more about your application, device, input signal.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Schottky diode forward biased.

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en//SB140/SB140FSCT-ND

Comment: Link Broken....

Comment: not very well defined voltage without source current limit..DK bug on search links until subcategory defined

Answer (score 0):

Any zener-like performance demands a specified current for the voltage limit and a tolerance.

When Voltage reaches 0.4V does that affect ADC result?
Will driver provide necessary current of 10mA without loading effects?
Will it Limit voltage with 30mA?  That's what you want.

The BAT54 is the lowest cost signal Schottky diode that can be made to regulate with a lower specified current limit at 0.4 to 0.5V for example.
[image]

With higher loop gain using a precision bandgap , ratios and comparator, a better clamp can be designed once your full requirements are made clear for linear range and non-linear voltage limit.   This is possible but not what you asked for.